# Pipenv & lock file - depolyment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I have just started using PIPENV and I found it amazing as I have never used virtual environments before. However, I am still confused with the PIPENV file and the lock file. I understand through videos that both files are essential for PIPENV.

I have two questions regarding the two files:

1) If I wish to deploy it on my friends laptop (lets take him as the end user), which of those two files do I need to pass him and what are their purposes?

2) If I wish to deploy it on my other friends laptop (lets take him as my project partner) who requires development libraries, which of those two files do I need to pass him and what are their purposes?

3) What is the difference between 'freeze' and 'lock'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pipfile` is the file describing which dependencies are directly needed by your application.

`Pipfile.lock` is generated from `Pipfile` and describes everything that needs to be installed for your application to work, i.e. your direct dependencies, their dependencies etc.

Answering your questions 1 and 2, you should ship both `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` in both scenarios.

However, the installation process will be slightly different.

An end user would need to install the dependencies with `pipenv install --deploy` to make sure that `Pipfile.lock` is fresh -- the installation will fail if the lockfile is out of date.

Another developer of your project might install the dependencies with plain `pipenv install`. If `Pipfile.lock` is out of date, it will be regenerated during installation.

---

Answering your question 3: `freeze` is a `pip` command, not a `pipenv` command.

`pip freeze` prints **current contents** of your virtual environment in a text format, and its output is typically saved in a file named `requirements.txt`. If your virtual environment is somehow out of date, its contents will still be output as-is.

`pipenv lock` builds and outputs the **project's dependency list**, whether or not they are currently installed. It generates the lockfile under the name `Pipfile.lock` for further usage with `pipenv`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I am still confused as why do we need to transfer the lock file when both scenarios will either regenerate or build a new lock file.

Comment: The first scenario will not regenerate the lockfile, it will fail if it is missing or out-of-date. The second scenario will indeed regenerate the lockfile if needed, but I'd recommend to pass it anyway because it allows you to make sure that dependencies are the same on your and your partner's computer.